# Will the try method and the && operator serve the same purpose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose there is a model `user.rb`. And I have a method define `firstname`.

```
def firstname
 shipping_address.try(:firstname)
end

def firstname
  shipping_address && shipping_address.firstname
end
```

In both cases we are trying avoid unwanted exceptions. Is that what try is being used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`&&` cancels further application of any **expression** following it when it is **preceded by a falsy value**. When the following expression is not executed, the return value is the value preceding `&&`, i.e., either `false` or `nil`.

`try` **evaluates all arguments** that are meant to be passed with the **method** in question, and cancels the application of the method when it is **not defined**. When the method call is not performed, the return value is `nil`.

Comment: I think the essence is the same. I know && performs short-circuiting but a statement like `shipping_address && shipiing_address.try(:firstname)' won't make sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does the same in this very example, however since ruby 2.3 we have a new operator for this, called "safe navigation operator":

```
def firstname
  shipping_address&.firstname
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence, Yes.

Remember, it is added by `rails`. So it will not work in plain `ruby` projects.

Refer to [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As @dharam already said, the `#try` method is a Rails method and `&&` is plain ruby. The [source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) of it is pretty straightforward. But no they are not the same since as @sawa already said - `&&` the operation cancels if an expression is `nil` of `false`.

Here the source code (`#try`, without bang, uses this method):

```
def try!(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    if b.arity == 0
      instance_eval(&b)
    else
      yield self
    end
  else
    public_send(*a, &b)
  end
end
```